# Google Apps Scripts: Possible to automatically set GSheet to "Compact Controls" View?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

was just wondering whether you can, via Google Apps Scripts, automatically turn on the "Compact Controls" setting under the View menu, specifically in Google Sheets, so that when the user opens up the sheet it automatically has this view.

Have searched the Reference for this and cannot find anything relevant.  I understand that client-side user controls are pretty tightly circumscribed codewise.  Any and all advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not possible to do that with apps script. there is really nothing you can do to the way things look outside of the cell ranges (maximize, hide toolbar, ful screen etc)

a browser extension (i.e. a chrome extension) can do this but the other users would need to have it.

Comment: Thanks Zig, if any browser extensions for this purpose come to mind, please let me know.